# Python hashlib md5 different output and slow speed compared to bash md5sum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I have two problems I'm trying to solve. 1) When I run hashlib md5 I'm getting a different output than when I run md5sum in bash. 2) Running the program in python takes much longer than bash.

Also, I have a table of md5sum values I want to match this test file and others to. The bash output in my test case matches the value I was provided in the table. So ideally I would like to get the python output to match that.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import os
import hashlib
import gzip
import time
import subprocess

def get_gzip_md5(in_file):
    #gets the md5sum value for a given file
    
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    chunk = 8192
    
    with gzip.open(in_file, "rb") as f:
        
        while True:
            buffer = f.read(chunk)
            if not buffer:
                break
            hash_md5.update(buffer)

    return hash_md5.hexdigest()

t0 = time.process_time()

out = subprocess.run("md5sum test.fastq.gz", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(out.stdout)

t1 = time.process_time() - t0
print("Time elapsed:",t1)


t0 = time.process_time()

md5 = get_gzip_md5("test.fastq.gz")
print(md5)

t1 = time.process_time() - t0
print("Time elapsed:",t1)
```

Output:

```
b'b0a25d66a1a83582e088f062983128ed  test.fastq.gz\n'
Time elapsed: 0.007306102000256942
cfda2978db7fab4c4c5a96c61c974563
Time elapsed: 95.02966231200026
```

Comment: It's easily seen... and easily missable, as it is a subtle detail in a quick look. Your bash MD5 is computing the checksum of the original compressed file. By using `gzip.open` for your python MD5, you are uncompressing the file and, accordingly, computing the MD5 of the uncompressed file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from how you opened your file in `Python`.

**Short Answer:**

You need to change

```
gzip.open(in_file, "rb")
```

by

```
open(in_file, "rb")
```

And you'll have the same MD5 sum.

**Long answer:**

`gzip.open()` will uncompress your `.gz` file and will read it's content in `rb` mode. however in the same time, `md5sum` will process the MD5 sum of the compressed file. So, it'll lead to different MD5 sum values.

How to solve this issue ? Simply, `open` the compressed file in `rb` and get it's MD5 sum without uncompressing it.